# Deploying Angular app in a different folder than root folder ng build base href

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-universal

```
"build": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
            "options": {
              "outputPath": "dist/browser",
              "index": "src/index.html",
              "main": "src/main.ts",
              "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
              "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "assets": [
                "src/favicon.ico",
                "src/assets"
              ],
              "styles": [
                "./node_modules/video.js/dist/video-js.min.css",
                "./node_modules/@videojs/themes/dist/city/index.css",
                "./node_modules/@videojs/themes/dist/sea/index.css",
                "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                "src/styles.css"
            ],
              "scripts": []
            }
```

I have used the above configuration  and use **"ng build --prod --base-href /v2/ --deploy-url /v2/ "** command so when i run the application all js files and css files are not found.

i am getting **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" error.**

after i tried to access js file "http://localhost:8080/v2/runtime.js" but it didnt found.

i also checked all scripts are generated as below

```
<script src="/v2/runtime.js" defer="">
</script><script src="/v2/polyfills-es5.js" nomodule="" defer=""></script>
<script src="/v2/polyfills.js" defer=""></script>
```

I have tried multiple options but didn't get a luck.

Comment: In order this to work, your configuration must be `"outputPath": "dist/v2"`.

Comment: I did but still, the same problem exist.

Comment: Show your webserver config and folder structure

Answer (score 0):

you can check the base tag that needs to be like this

```
<base href="/v2/">
```

(in index.html)

Comment: I also did the same things. i set base href as you can see ng build --prod --base-href /v2/ --deploy-url /v2/ "

Comment: after building the project, how did you run ? have you use the apache2 server? and what your os?